# Biharmonic equation in  spherical coordinates

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

What is a general solution of biharmonic equation
$\nabla^2\nabla^2f=0$
in spherical coordinates?

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biharmonic_equation) any solution of Laplace equation is also a solution of biharmonic equation, but the vice versa is not always true. Therefore I assume there exists a more general solution.

According to [Oberbeck, A., Crelle, 62, 1876](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/crll.1876.81.62), a general solution of biharmonic equation in spherical coordinates is
$\label{eq:Fsol}
 F=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{A_n+B_nr^2}{r^{2n+1}}r^nK_n \;,
$ 
where $K_n$ is a spherical function of order $n$. How to show that this holds (if it does)?